# Azure Function service bus topic trigger in TypeScript - Batch

Tags: typescript, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

Is that possible to batch fetch data from service bus in Azure Function service bus topic trigger
created in TypeScript?
In C# we can do this like this:

```
public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("topic", "subscription", Connection = "SERVICEBUS", IsBatched = true)] string[] myQueueItem)
```

Thanks!

Im expecting to fetch array of data from service bus in Azure function that was created in typescript

Answer (score -1):

Create the Azure Function: Set up your Azure Function in TypeScript. You can define your function with a Service Bus topic trigger and specify the necessary connection and trigger settings.

```
import { AzureFunction, Context } from "@azure/functions";
import { ServiceBusMessage } from "@azure/service-bus";

const topicTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (
  context: Context,
  messages: ServiceBusMessage[]
): Promise<void> {
  context.log(`Received ${messages.length} messages`);

  // Process the messages in batches
  for (const message of messages) {
    // Perform your desired processing on each message
    context.log(`Processing message: ${message.body}`);
  }
};
export default topicTrigger;
```

In the above example, the function topicTrigger is triggered when messages are received from the specified Service Bus topic. The messages parameter is an array of ServiceBusMessage objects, representing the batch of messages received.

Configure the function.json file: In the same directory as your Azure Function, create or update the function.json file to specify the trigger details, including the connection string, topic name, and subscription name.

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "serviceBusTrigger",
      "name": "messages",
      "direction": "in",
      "topicName": "your-topic-name",
      "subscriptionName": "your-subscription-name",
      "connection": "SERVICEBUS",
      "isBatch": true
    }
  ]
}
```

By setting isBatch to true in the function.json file and providing an array parameter in the function definition, you can receive messages in batches from the Service Bus topic trigger in your Azure Function created using TypeScript.

Comment: But i guess, in Azure Function V4 it's not possible to create this like that(?)